# How to restream an RTSP stream without processing anything on linux computer?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, embedded, rtsp

I am working with Embedded Linux machine which can get the RTSP stream from other source. Now if I configure my FFMPEG and try to restream it, the CPU usage reaches very high. This probably is due to Embedded Hardware capability.

Is there any possible way we can simply restream the incoming stream with out processing it at all using any type of library?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a command for GStreamer. My guess ([from here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/live-stream-repeat-reencode-td2968001.html)):

```
gst-launch -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://url" ! rtph264depay ! \
   rtph264pay ! udpsink port=15000 sync=false
```